# How to set the default value of an integer field to it's possible maximum?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, laravel-schema-builder

Is there any way to set a maximum value as a default one for an integer field? In other words, I'm looking for a simple and elegant way to replace the hardcoded `999` value from the code below.

```php
Schema::create('files', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    // . . .
    $table->integer('display_order')->default(999); // <-- MAX_VALUE instead of 999
    // . . .
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that PHP has [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

> PHP_INT_MAX (integer) The largest integer supported in this build of
>   PHP. Usually int(2147483647). Available since PHP 5.0.5